# Set "global" proxy option?

Tags: c, libcurl

I've came across to an almost impossible to solve problem (at least I hope it's not impossible):

### Environment:

I need to use a library which involves network data transfers done by *cURL*. The library itself is closed source, but it also does GUI-handling, and provides a basic web-browser.

The library - just to see the whole view - is made for Tizen, and it provides OAuth2 solution (it can open a bundled-browser to show you the granting page for OAuth2).

### Current status:

OAuth2 library works perfectly, as long as the target device has its own network (either Wifi or Cellular).

### The problem:

On Tizen wearable, when the wearable doesn't have its own connectivity (but it can use the Bluetooth-connected phone's connection), one must use *proxy* to be able to use the connection: https://docs.tizen.org/application/native/guides/connectivity/curl/#manage

For this, Tizen's documentation recommends to use

> curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, ipv4_address);

That's all great, however their own OAuth2 manager doesn't uses this, hence, when the wearable doesn't have its own connectivity, OAuth2 can't function.

I have found online the `oauth2_manager`'s code, and what it does seems impossible to modify:

```
//my_code:
oauth2_manager_refresh_access_token(...)
-> calls a static function in the library (_request_refresh_token)
_request_refresh_token calls:
-> curl_easy_init()
-> curl_easy_setopt(...)
-> curl_easy_perform
-> curl_easy_cleanup
//then returns to my code.
```

`curl_easy_setopt` doesn't apply any proxy setting in the library (although the sources I have found are ancient, but still today it is not working, and error messages are matching with the ancient sources).

### Question

Can I set a global setting for cURL, which applies a specific CURLOPT_PROXY on every new connection? Note: `curl_easy_init` will called, so my desired setting of the proxy shall survive the easy_init.

Comment: You can set environment variables `http_proxy` and `https_proxy`. Then libcurl should use those by default.

Comment: Hm. Something like this: `putenv("https_proxy=A.B.C.D"); oauth2_manager_refresh_access_token(...); putenv("https_proxy");` ? `putenv` seems available on the platform, but I'm not sure if it's allowed to call.

Comment: Typically those environment variables contain something like `http://A.B.C.D`.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. Even `putenv("http_proxy=A.B.C.D"); curl_easy_init(); ... curl_easy_perform();` Gives access denied.

Comment: It just seems `curl` is not respecting any environment variable on the platform.

Answer (score 0):

Tizen wearable device connects with the phone using SPP(Serial Port Profile) profile.
It is connected via BT link and transfer the data. So there is no network interface to use 'data network'.
Wifi and Cellular case, it establish the own network connection and enable to use 'network interface'.
So Bluetooth is different with Wifi and Cellualr.

If Tizen wearable supports 'BT tethering' and connected with phone via BT tethering, then it creates the 'pan0' interface.
So works with Wifi and Celluar samely.
But, Tizen wearable does not support 'BT tethering' and can't connect using tethering.
As I said, only connected using SPP profile.

At result, the physical link and the connected method is totally different from wifi and cellular.
So we can answer that that functionality is not supported on Tizen wearable.

Thanks